# Out of Office autamatic replies don't pick up signatures

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010.
When OOO is turned on, text added to automatic reply is sent to proper recepient but signature is not sent.
Is there anyway to have signature sent automatically with OOO reply?

Answer (score 2):

Add your signature under the custom text for the auto-reply. Job done.

Comment: This, set OOO for clients that leave their businesses all the time. Only way is to copy and paste their signature.